# Difference between shutdown menu and keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shutdown

Does anybody know the difference between <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>⌃  Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Optn</kbd>+<kbd>⏏ Media Eject</kbd> and the `Apple Menu` --> `Shut Down...` button? Just asking, because the menu button takes 15s to shut down, whereas the keyboard shortcut is under half a second.

Answer (score 0):

[This Lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5831557/shut-down-or-reboot-your-mac-immediately-with-a-keyboard-command) says that using this shortcut command closes everything down without saving. That conflicts with [Apple's official documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) which says you do have the opportunity to save open documents.

I didn't test, but if Lifehacker is right, then this would make sense. Using the shortcut circumvents certain OS functions, such as saving application state or checking for changed documents and goes straight to the good part: Shutting down your computer.